# cakephp retrieve all translation

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I would like to know how to retrieve translation inside a query with cakephp 3.3.
I have already added inside Table:

```
$this->addBehavior('Translate', ['fields' => ['textContent']]);
```

This is my query:

```
$query = $objTable->find('all')
     ->where(['admin_template_id' => $id])
     ->contain(['AdminObjects']);
```

I have already tried this:

```
$query = $objTable->find('all')
         ->where(['admin_template_id' => $id])
         ->contain(['AdminObjects', 'translations']);
```

But returns me error 500.

My translation table is the same of the cakephp documentation:

```
CREATE TABLE i18n (
    id int NOT NULL auto_increment,
    locale varchar(6) NOT NULL,
    model varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    foreign_key int(10) NOT NULL,
    field varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    content text,
    PRIMARY KEY     (id),
    UNIQUE INDEX I18N_LOCALE_FIELD(locale, model, foreign_key, field),
    INDEX I18N_FIELD(model, foreign_key, field)
);
```

How can I fin translation inside a find all query?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use find method 'translations' instate of 'all'.

try

```
$query = $objTable->find('translations')
 ->where(['admin_template_id' => $id])
 ->contain(['AdminObjects']);
```

instate of

```
$query = $objTable->find('all')
 ->where(['admin_template_id' => $id])
 ->contain(['AdminObjects']);
```

officeial Doc [Retrieve All Translations](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/behaviors/translate.html#retrieve-all-translations-for-an-entity)